# Proving that $f$ is continuous at $3$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

We have the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=x^2+3x-5$ and want to show that it is continuous at $3$. This is how I've done it

**Proof:**

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Take $\delta=\mbox{min}\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{10}\}$ and suppose that $|x-3|<\delta$. We note that for $|x-3|<1$, we have $|x+6|=|x-3+9|\leq|x-3|+9<1+9=10$. Therefore, we have the following:

\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(3)|&=|x^2+3x-18|\\
&=|x-3||x+6|\\
&<\delta\cdot 10\\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}{10}\cdot10\\
&=\varepsilon\\
\end{align*}
$\blacksquare$

I'm wondering if this proof is sound. If somebody could verify this for me I would greatly appreciate it. I'm still quite new to epsilon-delta proofs. Any additional advice or pointers are always appreciated as well. Thanks

Comment: This is almost there (and maybe my comment is being a little too nitpicky, but here it is anyway). The step where you say $\delta = \epsilon/10$ is not quite right. The reason is, you don't know if $\delta = \epsilon/10$ or $\delta = 1$. Obviously in the case where $\epsilon/10 \leq 1$, $\delta$ is indeed $\epsilon/10$ and your proof is correct. In the case $\epsilon/10 > 1$, your $\delta = 1$ and we will have: $$\dots < \delta \cdot 10 < \epsilon/10 \cdot 10 = \epsilon$$

Comment: A good exercise to verify a solution is to try to drop the proof. Is there any part of the proof  that doesn't give you enough confidence that your proof is correct?

Answer (score 1):

From your second to last line... $\delta \cdot 10 \neq \frac{\varepsilon}{10} \cdot 10$.
$$  \delta \cdot 10 = \begin{cases}
\frac{\varepsilon}{10} \cdot 10 ,& \varepsilon/10 \leq 1  \\
1 \cdot 10 ,& \varepsilon/10 > 1
\end{cases}  \text{.}  $$
The first case is, of course, $\varepsilon$, but the second is not.

In the second case, from $\varepsilon/10 > 1$, you have $\varepsilon > 10$, so $\delta \cdot 10 = 1 \cdot 10 < \varepsilon$ in this case.

If your audience would automatically understand this detail, you could correctly write
$$  \delta \cdot 10 \leq \min\{1, \varepsilon/10\} \cdot 10 = \min\{10,\varepsilon\} \leq \varepsilon  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So if I were to break the last 5 lines of my proof into two cases, one where $\delta=1$ and one where $\delta=\varepsilon/10$, then it would work?

Comment: Actually, if I were to say in the second to last line... $\delta\cdot10\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{10}\cdot10$, wouldn't that solve the problem?  Because it would then take into account the other case?

Comment: @Gteal : There is a difference between "logically implied" and "intelligibly follows from".  The Answer already warns that the shortcut that is presented is only for an audience that would automatically understand the issue.  Abbreviating further begs for a reader to be convinced you are either wrong or have skipped explanation of crucial steps.